# Navigation menu not in position

Tags: php, html, css

Can't seem to find what's wrong with the navigation menu layout... it is not centered on the div container. By the way its not the original menu, it was pure css menus without graphics at first but with the same problem. Since I can't find what is wrong I grab a working example, but the same problem when included with my code.

Please help... thanks.

[image]

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="header-cont">
        <div class="header">
            <img src="images/header.png"></img>
            <?php   require ("testnavigation.php"); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content-container1">


        <div id="section-navigation">
            <p>sidebar navigation</p>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>contents here</p>
        </div>

        <div id="aside">
            <h3>Aside heading</h3>
            <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit
                esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla
                facilisis at vero eros et accumsan.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Copyright © Site name, 20XX</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the css

```
body {
    //font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    //font-size: 12px;
    background: #0E2B43;
}

.header-cont {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.header > img {
    horizontal-align: middle;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header {
    height: 122px;
    background: #333;
    //border: 1px solid #CCC; 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    //width: 966px;
    background: #33FF99;
}

#header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

#content-container1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e9eaed;
    margin: 122px auto;
}

#content-container2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 2%;
}

#content h2 {
    margin: 0;
}

#aside {
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 2% 0 0;
    display: inline;
}

#aside h3 {
    margin: 0;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 1%;
}

#content h1 { //
    margin: 1em 0 0.5em 0;
    color: #343434;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 40px; //
    font-family: 'Orienta', sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(53, 86, 129, 0.3);
}

/* These are used on the sidebar */
#section-navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 16%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 2%;
    display: inline; //
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#section-navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#section-navigation ul li {
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#section-navigation li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0px 0 0;
    width: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* These are used on the sidebar */

/* These are used on the header navigation */
.clearer {
    clear: both;
}

#navigation-row {
    background: #aeb5b8 url("images/navigation-bg.gif") repeat-x left top;
    height: 38px;
    border-left: solid 1px #818b8f;
    border-right: solid 1px #818b8f;
    //width: 920px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

ul#navigation {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    background: url("images/nav-spacer.gif") repeat-y -1px top;
    height: 38px;
}

ul#navigation li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: url("images/nav-spacer.gif") repeat-y right top;
    height: 38px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}

ul#navigation li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #313a3e;
    text-decoration: none;
   // text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

ul#navigation li a:hover, ul#navigation li a.active {
    background: url("images/nav-bg-hover.gif") repeat-x left top;
}
```

This is the navigation.php

```
<div id="navigation-row">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</font></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="search">
                <form action="search.php" method="POST">
                    <input name="search" type="text" maxlength="30" class="textfield"
                        value="search" />

                </form>
            </div>

        <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've posted a LOT of irrelevant code, please remove all but the navigation specific stuff. Looking at the image it appears to be a problem with padding or margins in your navigation elements. Have you inspected the elements with developer tools?

Comment: Sorry about that, I included everything because like I said I can't find where the source of the problem, don't know which may be relevant or not to find the problem. I did everything to my knowledge, tinkering with the inspect element in chrome. opps forgot to tell Im a newbie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your `ul#navigation` is inheriting the default user agent's stylesheet, which in Chrome has a margin of 16px. If you add `margin: 0;` to that rule, I think you might get what you want.

Comment: No problem. On a side note, I'd suggest you to try to use a more semantic markup. Tags like `<main>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<article>`, `<section>`… provide a better readability (for humans and machines). Also, [flexbox](css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can help you writing a cleaner stylesheet when laying out your elements.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed these two lines

```
ul#navigation li a {
    float: left; /* removed this */
    line-height: 38px; /* removed this */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ykKkL/2/

Comment: Hi, thanks but its partly solve the alignment, removing what you said and adding the margin: 0 by gtramontina made the alignment more better... but still not centered.

Comment: remove only float: left and added margin: 0 to ul#navigation by gtramontina, finally solves the problem.... Thanks a lot guys, but my problem now is who will I give credit to since your answers both help solving the problem?